# How to prevent image proportions changing when resizing view port

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I make my image my background once I get to a high enough screen size the image seems to be zoomed in on. However, I want the proportions to stay the same at all times, below is the photo. I want the path in it to be visible at all tiems and not cropped out. [image]

html below :

```
 <section class="section-landing background-image"></section>
```

css below :

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url(/images/main-background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"VH" is a height property that scales with the height of the screen.

For example, 100vh means that it's 100% of the screen height at all times. So increasing the screen height would "zoom in" the photo since the "background-size" is set to cover the available space of the element.

If you want it to stay one size, specify the correct fixed size in your "background-size" attribute.

Comment: For reference, see [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).